# fundamental group of torus with segment that connecting two points of it

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be the topological space obtained by gluing on torus a segment that connecting two point of torus. Use Seifert Van Kampen's theorem to calculate the fundamental group of X.
I try to compute it but I can't do it.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely how $X$ is constructed? Do you mean that you attach $[0,1]$ to the torus $T$ via an injective map $\{ 0,1 \} \to T$?

Comment: Isn't this the same as the question you asked (and I answered) earlier?

Comment: No, it’s another exercise

Comment: The segment that connetting two points of Torus is attached to the torus. I must compute fundamental group of space formed by torus with this segment

Comment: In the last question torus was constructed attacching two points, in this question torus is constructed attacching a segment that connetting two points

Comment: can you see that this is homotopic to  $T^2 \vee S^1$? Do you know what $\pi_1(X \vee Y)$ is when both spaces are, say locally contractible (or CW complexes)

Comment: Actually @Antonio it would be instructive to show that this space is homotopic to the space you mentioned in the last question.

Comment: do you mean that this space formed by torus with segment that connetting two points of torus is homotopic to T2 v S1? why?